# how to remove a from 1st level UL?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

bellow is my code from wordpress. i want to remove all a (link) from 1st level ul li (say International gTLDs, Commercial ccTLDs, Australasia ccTLDs, Europe & America ccTLDs ) but under `<ul class="sub-menu">`a will be not remove. please suggest me how by jquery

```
<div class="sitemap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="general/international-gtlds/">International gTLDs</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="com-net-org-info/">.COM/.NET/.ORG/.INFO</a></li>
    <li><a href="biz/">.BIZ</a></li>
    <li><a href="name/">.NAME</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobi/">.MOBI</a></li>
    <li><a href="travel/">.TRAVEL</a></li>
    <li><a href="asia/">.ASIA</a></li>
    <li><a href="tel/">.TEL</a></li>
    <li><a href="xxx/">.XXX</a></li>
    <li><a href="xxx-sunrise-and-landrush/">.XXX (Sunrise and Landrush)</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="category/domain-faqs/general/commercial/">Commercial ccTLDs</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="cc/">.CC</a></li>
    <li><a href="tv/">.TV</a></li>
    <li><a href="cd/">.CD</a></li>
    <li><a href="cm/">.CM</a></li>
    <li><a href="me/">.ME</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="category/domain-faqs/general/australasia/">Australasia ccTLDs</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="au/">.AU</a></li>
    <li><a href="nz-registration/">.NZ Registration</a></li>
    <li><a href="cx/">.CX</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="category/domain-faqs/general/europe/">Europe &amp; America ccTLDs</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="europe-america-cctlds/">.EU</a></li>
    <li><a href="us/">.US</a></li>
    <li><a href="de/">.DE</a></li>
    <li><a href="li/">.LI</a></li>
    <li><a href="it/">.IT</a></li>
    <li><a href="la/">.LA</a></li>
    <li><a href="mx-domain/">.MX</a></li>
    <li><a href="uk/">.UK</a></li>
    <li><a href="co/">.CO</a></li>
    <li><a href="co-no/">.CO.NO</a></li>
    <li><a href="co-nl/">.CO.NL</a></li>
    <li><a href="fm/">.FM</a></li>
    <li><a href="gs/">.GS</a></li>
    <li><a href="tl/">.TL</a></li>
    <li><a href="ht/">.HT</a></li>
    <li><a href="ki/">.KI</a></li>
    <li><a href="mu/">.MU</a></li>
    <li><a href="nf/">.NF</a></li>
    <li><a href="ag/">.AG</a></li>
    <li><a href="bz/">.BZ</a></li>
    <li><a href="hn/">.HN</a></li>
    <li><a href="lc/">.LC</a></li>
    <li><a href="sc/">.SC</a></li>
    <li><a href="vc/">.VC</a></li>
    <li><a href="tr/">.TR</a></li>
    <li><a href="ws/">.WS</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove just the hyperlink or the text as well? You could just bind a click event that has `return false;` for those `<a>` elements.

Comment: i want to remove only hyperlink not text

Comment: Remove the link completely or just stop it being _clickable_?

Comment: Remove, disable, change into just regular text. I think you'll need to explain the wanted behaviour a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the hyperlink you can bind a [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event handler with jQuery to catch the `click` and stop the default action propagating and following the hyperlink.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.sitemap > ul > li > a').click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Or** to remove the `<a>` entirely, you can use:

```
$('.sitemap > ul > li > a').contents().unwrap();
```

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cRQ6S/1/)

**Edit:** Thanks to @adeneo on the noconflict tip for wordpress

Comment: thanks guys for you guide... i figureout it.. that is

$('.sitemap > ul > li > a').contents().unwrap();

http://jsfiddle.net/cRQ6S/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('.sitemap > ul > li > a').replaceWith(function(){
        return $(this).text()
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/66pdB/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cRQ6S/ .. not really work.. check this.. i checked your one it that name also remove .. i just want to remove a(link) but keep word like now <li><a href="general/international-gtlds/">International gTLDs</a>...i want International gTLDs only

Answer (score 0):

You want `<a href="general/international-gtlds/">International gTLDs</a>` to be removed completely?

`$("div.sitemap>ul>li>a").remove();`

Comment: nah just remove a (link) but keep International gTLDs